# CentOs 6-x_64 Setting DISPLAY variable

Tags: linux, bash

Have VPS server. Trying to set the display variable. Have always had problems with the correct value.

## setenv $DISPLAY = :0.0

## export $DISPLAY

Tring to get xinit not to fail due to no VT being set or found. xhost + and setting the $DISPLAY variable will allow all X Sessions to run and any gui will come up. I am 3 weeks into CentOs and come from a Unix environment so for the bash shell what is the correct way to get gui's up for CentOs 6.8-x_64.

Regards-

Answer (score 2):

If you have a headless CentOS and want to run GUI Apps by logging in remotely you will need to :

1. yum install xorg-x11-xauth
2. yum install xorg-x11-apps
3. ssh -X yourserver
4. xclock

Obvioulsy you need to run ssh -X from the system running X11 server.

- If you are on Linux - no extra steps needed.
- If you are on Mac OS X - install XQuartz
- If you are on Windows - use either xming, mobaxterm, Exceed or anything else that adds X11 support.

Comment: yum already installed x-org*    Installed xming  ssh -X myserver xclock error can't open display DISPLAY=:0.0; export DISPLAY xclock error can't open DISPLAY :0.0 can't set the VT for X to run?

Comment: is xorg-x11-xauth installed ?

Comment: xorg-x11-xauth is needed for X forwarding to work

Comment: Yes xorg-x11-xauth is installed!

Comment: Check this link http://www.astro.yale.edu/astr255/xming-install/xming-putty-ssh-palan.html

Comment: Exact steps which I described work on a brand new CentOS 6 installed just with the bare minimum of packages - core group. I was testing X forwarding from Mac and also from Windows running Mobaxterm. Since you are using xming (and putty?) perhaps something is not right in this area. Make sure that in putty you have X forwarding selected. Make sure that on CentOS in sshd_config you have X Forwarding enabled (it's enabled by default), make sure that your xming is actually running versus just installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `bash` and you need to set the `DISPLAY` variable (I'd expect it to be set automatically in general) then the correct syntax is

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

or

```
DISPLAY=:0.0; export DISPLAY
```

`setenv` is a `csh` command so not used here. Note that you mustn't use the dollar sign with the variable name and no spaces either side of the equals sign.

Comment: Still can't get xserver started! Maybe I can't on this server?